# The latest application is not deployed in wso2cloud

Tags: deployment, build, wso2, wso2-cloud

It seems to me like the latest code that I submitted to WSO2 App cloud is not deployed. I tried to access the jenkins server (https://jenkins.cloud.wso2.com/t/cleancoders/webapps/jenkins/job/draft-trunk-default/) I see there that the latest code is built(upto build 29) but on the App cloud still build 24 is deployed. It seems to like the jenkins builds are not synced and deployed.

I also tried to build and deploy manually but It seems that it is not having an effect.

Please suggest what should be done in order to deploy the latest build.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a kind of problem which you can get when your app is not properly deployed in jenkins. (There may be configuration issues). Please do contact cloud@wso2.com for assistance.